# php password_verify still not working

Tags: php, sql

I have read many articles on this password_hash and has applied as much as I can if not all the things I read about it
Still the password_verify still refuses to authenticate values no matter how much I tried. PHP Version 5.61.6 and SQL version 5.7.9
any form of help is appreciated, am already exhausted from trying many string combinations

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Administrator</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
         <?PHP
            //.......all variables are collected from html form....
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "uname", "pword", "dbname");
            mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');
            //.......`SN` column has the unique attribute
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM Sign_Up WHERE `SN`=$sn";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $date = date('Y-m-j g:i:s');
                    //.......idgen is a function previously defined
                    $id = idgen();
                    //.......prints $id before hashing....
                    echo $id."<BR>";
                    $id = password_hash('$id', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                    //......string length before storing
                   echo strlen($id)."<BR>";
                   //......table columns
                   $f = $row["FirstName"];
                   $l = $row["LastName"];
                   $bn = $row["BusinessName"];
                   $ba = $row["BusinessAddress"];

                   $sq = "INSERT INTO Distributors (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `BusinessName`, `BusinessAddress`) VALUES ('$f', '$l', '$bn', '$ba')";
                   $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sq);
                 }
            }
        ?>

    </body>
 </html>
```

And the code for verifying the hash is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        <?PHP

            $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');
            //.....phone number has a unique attribute
            $sql = "SELECT `ID` FROM Distributors WHERE `PhoneNumber`='number'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            $result1= mysqli_num_rows($result);
            $look = mysqli_fetch_array($result)['ID'];
            print $look."<BR>";
            $look = trim($look);
            print $look."<BR>";
            print strlen($look)."<BR>";
            //......all print statements yields expected results and hashed password is stored
            //......in VARCHAR (255)...I also tried CHAR 
            $ver = password_verify('user input data', '$look');
                if ($ver) {

                    print "ok";
                }
                else {
                    print "no";
                }


     ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You hashing the literal string`$id`... and in verify testing against the literal string `$look`. Learn how to use [PHP strings](http://php.net/string).

Comment: `password_verify('user input data', '$look');` Really? comparing a password string of `user input data` with a hashed value that looks like `$look`?!?

Comment: ...and you're verifying the literal string `$look`.

Comment: And in registration: `$id = password_hash('$id', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`.... this will create a password hash for a literal string of `$id`, not of the variable value stored in `$id`

Comment: AND you're modifying the password before passing it to verify...

Comment: Basically..... stop using single quotes wrapped around variables

Comment: AND you're not saving your hashed "password".

Comment: AND why are you even trying to hash an ID?

Comment: I think the most interesting question is... what are you trying to do here? What is your code suppose to do?

Comment: No am not verifying the literal string $look. Its a variable and the user-input-data comes from a $_POST variable from a HTML form

Comment: That ID is a form of password. The whole idea is to create a distraction for any hacker that successfully hacks the database

Comment: @OrchidEngr '$look' is the literal string $look...

Comment: My code is trying to verify variable $id that was generated when a user registered against the one that is generated when the same user performs any transaction

Comment: Thanks guys, its resolved now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use php variables without any quote or inside double quotes, `""`:

```
$id = password_hash($id, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);         // no quotes around $id

$ver = password_verify('user input data', "$look"); // double quotes around $look
```

Single quote strings are not parsed i.e. treated as literal strings while double quoted strings are parsed and therefore variables names are expanded with their values.

Comment: I have tried removing all quotes both when the variable is hashed and when it is verified and it still doesn't work

Comment: Sorry for the wrong comment. You are right I can't tell you how happy I am. Its the quotes. I was hashing $id and not the content of the variable

Answer (score 0):

When hashing use:

```
$id = "school";
Password_hash($id);
```

When verifying use:

```
Password_verify($id, $data_from_database);
```